# How to specify network when provisioning in vagrant

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile, vagrant-provision

I have multiple networks specified in my vagrantfile and only one of them are accessible from outside. When the vagrant starts provisioning, sometimes it chooses the wrong network (IP) to connect to the VM and it fails. Is it possible to specify which network should vagrant choose when provisioning? If not, I would like to know how vagrant chooses which IP to use when provisioning.

Comment: I have a this problem too